# Repetir los dígitos de un número en Maxima

Tags: matemáticas, maxima

Necesito hacer una función en Maxima que repita k veces los dígitos de un número n. Por ejemplo,

`repetirDigitos(41,4) = 41414141`

`repetirDigitos(24,3) = 242424`

`repetirDigitos(14,7) = 14141414141414`

He intentado convertir el número n en una cadena (string), y repetirlo las k veces necesarias. Pero, he buscado en distintos manuales y no encuentro ninguna función que haga eso.

Este es el código que tengo

```
(%i1)   log10(n) :=
        log(n) / log(10)$


    nDigitos(n) :=
        if n = 0  then 1
        else floor(log10(n)) +1$

(%i2)   nDigitos(3^64);
(%o1)   31

(%i3)   repetirNumero(n,k) :=
      repeat(k,readline(n))$
```

NOTA.-  Todo el código es parte del ejercicio que quiero hacer, pero me he quedado atascado en la función `repetirNumero(n,k)`

Comment: Hola. Puedes añadir más explicacion como qué lenguaje usas y los ejemplos de codigo que has intentado para ver qué errores concretos o problemas tienes?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para mejorar la pregunta y poder ayudarte. Un saludo

Comment: Vale, el lenguaje que uso es Maxima (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima)

Comment: Pones que te has quedado atascado en `repetirNumero` pero no hay ningun intento... algo habrás probado, y algun error o problema concreto habrás tenido no?

Comment: Llevas totalmente razón @lois6b  La función `readline(n)` la he encontrado en un manual, y  `repeat` no sé si existe, no encuentro ninguna función que repita elementos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la función `repetirNumero(n,k)` has de usar un block para concatenar expresiones:

Dentro del bloque inicializas un string vacío con `num: ""`, luego haces un bucle `for` que vaya desde `i:1` hasta `k` (siendo el parametro que indica cuantas veces ha de repetirse el numero `n`).

Dentro del `for` usas `sconcat` que es una funcion que concatena dos variables, y se lo asiganmos a `num` tal que: `num : sconcat(num, n)`

Despues, añado un `num` para que el resultado de `num` sea el return de la función.

Código:

```
repetirNumero(n,k) :=  
    block( 
        num:"", 
        for i:1 thru k  do 
            num : sconcat(num, n), 
        num
    );

repetirNumero(24,3);
```

Output:

```
(%i1) repetirNumero(n,k) :=  block( num:"", for i:1 thru k  do num : sconcat(num, n), num);
(%o1) repetirNumero(n, k) := block(num : "", 
                                    for i thru k do num : sconcat(num, n), num)
(%i2) repetirNumero(24,3);
(%o2)                               242424
(%i3)
```

<sub>Nota: Es la primera vez que hago algo en este lenguaje. No se si es la mejor forma o si hay cosas reduntantes o innecesarias.</sub>

Comment: Muchas gracias. Para ser la primera vez, es uan definición muy elaborada. ¿Te has apoyado en algún manual? Es que me vedría bien alguno. Un saludo.

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar tenia un rato libre por la mañana y me puse a *googlear* como un loco hahah y mucha prueba y error en http://maxima-online.org/